# Error while running kubectl commands

Tags: kubernetes

I have recently installed minikube and kubectl. However when I run `kubectl get pods` or any other command related to kubectl I get the error

`Unable to connect to the server: unexpected EOF`

Does anyone know how to fix this?I am using Ubuntu server 16.04.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following steps can be used for further debugging.

1. Check the minikube local cluster status using `minikube status` command.

   ```
    $: minikube status
    minikube: Running
    cluster: Running
    kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 172.0.x.y
   ```
2. If problem with kubectl configuratuion,then configure it using, `kubectl config use-context minikube` command.

   ```
   $: kubectl config use-context minikube
   Switched to context "minikube".
   ```
3. Check the cluster status, using `kubectl cluster-info` command.

   ```
   $: kubectl cluster-info
   Kubernetes master is running at ...
   Heapster is running at ...
   KubeDNS is running at ...
   ...
   To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
   ```

Note: It can even be due to very simple reason: internet speed (it happend to me just now).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too. I solved after change the `server` addr to `localhost`

```
  apiVersion: v1
  clusters:
  - cluster:
      certificate-authority: /var/lib/minikube/certs/ca.crt
      server: https://localhost:8443 # check it 
    name: m01
...
  users:
  - name: m01
    user:
      client-certificate: /var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver.crt
      client-key: /var/lib/minikube/certs/apiserver.key
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your kubernetes master is not setup properly. You can check that by checking the following services in master node are in active state and running.

```
etcd2.service 
kube-apiserver.service          Kubernetes API Server
kube-controller-manager.service Kubernetes Controller Manager
kube-scheduler.service          Kubernetes Scheduler
```

Comment: How can the poster check these services, where should they look orat commands should they use?